# Swagger-UI and Ktor how to import swagger.json or .yaml file and start Swagger-UI?

Tags: kotlin, swagger, swagger-ui, ktor, projekktor

I have a problem, I have already generated OpenApi Swagger files (swagger.json and swagger.yaml) Is it possible somehow in Ktor (kotlin) import this files and start swagger-ui server on specific route ?
I have visited [ktor-swagger project](https://github.com/nielsfalk/ktor-swagger) but could get how just to add json file to display swagger-ui.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: currently, this lib does not support ktor 2.0. And probably maintainer stoped working on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Make you json file accessible from static routing**

1. Create "files" directory in resources dir
2. Use next code to routing static files from "files" dir

   ```
   routing {
       static("/static") {
           resources("files")
       }
       //...
   }
   ```
3. Lets name json file *"test.json"*, then put you it in "files" folder

so now you run the app and see this file by http://localhost:8080/static/test.json

**Then we need to install and configure OpenApiGen**

1. Add OpenApiGen dependencies you can find how to do this here https://github.com/papsign/Ktor-OpenAPI-Generator
2. Then use the following code

   ```
   install(OpenAPIGen) {
       serveSwaggerUi = true
       swaggerUiPath = "/swagger-ui"
   }
   ```

now you can use http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/static/test.json URL to see your file through the swagger UI

**Also, you can provide your own route to using redirection**

```
get("/api") {
   call.respondRedirect("/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/static/test.json", true)
}
```

this will allow you to use just http://localhost:8080/api